# Photoshop - Layer blending to add brightness and hue distort at the same time

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, blending

I'm trying to recreate this effect:

[image]

For the sake of simplicity, let's ignore the teal edges and just assume two white rectangles. I'm having trouble creating the color invert/difference with the brightness at the same time.

I tried:

- Making a black layer at 50% opacity (to create the darkened layer)
- Imported my rectangles from AI and set opacity to 70%
- Closest blending setting seemed to be "Overlay" but this did not produce any hue distortion as seen in the inspiration

### Question

How should I adjust my methods to achieve brightness / color inversion? Hopefully there are labor-saving options for this.

**Note:** (not sure exactly what kind of color distortion is used, can assume inversion for now)

**Note2:** Also note that I'm not trying to apply the color invert to the whole picture, just where the white rectangle is. I don't think similar questions have addressed this method.

Comment: @BillyKerr The main issue is getting the hue distort at the same time with brightening the background. I don't think that was addressed in your linked question.

Answer (score 3):

Insert an adjustment layer "Curves" to be able to make non-destructive tweaks. A curve which partially inverts colors in midtones is probably what you want. Before it you can apply levels which brings the background from grey to white, but that's not a must. Curves can do that as well in the same time, like in the next example:
[image]

Not asked:

Photoshop's curves is a pain to use. Some programs such as Paint.NET have an option to add arbitary polyline curves which settle just where one wants them to settle. Photoshop's curves have a resistant own will as you soon can see.

Here the effect (=partial midtone color inversion and contrast boost to make the BG white) is done in Paint.NET with Pyrochild Curves+ plugin. It's free like Paint.NET and allows much more free curves than Photoshop:

[image]